# Java Thread dies without notification

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, hashmap

I was testing the concurrency with a HashMap (for academic purposes). My goal was to throw some kind of exception related to modifying the structure of the map from multiple threads.

It ended up that the threads that have the task to put stuff in my hash map inexplicably die without throwing any kind of exception...

```
public class Test {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler h = new Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler() {
      public void uncaughtException(Thread th, Throwable ex) {
        System.out.println("Uncaught exception: " + ex);
      }
    };

    Thread a = new Thread(new MyTask("A"));
    Thread b = new Thread(new MyTask("B"));
    Thread c = new Thread(new MyTask("C"));
    Thread d = new Thread(new MyTask("D"));

    a.setUncaughtExceptionHandler(h);
    b.setUncaughtExceptionHandler(h);
    c.setUncaughtExceptionHandler(h);
    d.setUncaughtExceptionHandler(h);

    a.start();
    b.start();
    c.start();
    d.start();
    while (true) {
      System.out.println(MyTask.map.size());
    }
  }
}

public class MyTask implements Runnable {
  static AtomicInteger counter = new AtomicInteger(0);
  static Map<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
  String name;

  MyTask(String _name) {
    name = _name;
  }

  @Override
  public void run() {
    while (true) {
      counter.incrementAndGet();

      try {
        map.put(name + "_" + counter.get(), counter.get());
      } catch (RuntimeException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      }

      System.out.println(name + "_" + counter.get());
    }
   }
 }
```

If you run this, you'll notice that the threads will stop printing at some point and the size of the map does not change anymore. If you switch to a ConcurrentHashMap, everything works fine (it keeps printing forever).

Please let me know how to catch such an exception / error!

Comment: It doesn't die, it goes into an infinite loop as HashMap is not thread safe. You wouldn't expect this to display an error, rather consume 100% of a CPU.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think there is an exception or error occurring. Referring to the [Javadoc of `HashMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html):

> **Note that this implementation is not synchronized**. If multiple threads access a hash map concurrently, and at least one of the threads modifies the map structurally, it must be synchronized externally.

You are modifying the map in multiple threads, and not synchronizing. As such, the behaviour is undefined.

Indeed, I cannot reproduce the behaviour that you describe: "this size of the map does not change any more"; I see long runs where the value appears not to change; but then eventually it changes to a new value, where it stays for a while.

The reason for this is that the changes in size resulting from the activity in the threads aren't being committed to main memory immediately.

Comment: It's not quite that the threads writes aren't being committed to memory. If you look at my link, it's a race condition between two or more writes. Even if all the fields were volatile, this can still fail.

Comment: Interesting! Thanks a lot. (:

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at http://mailinator.blogspot.com/2009/06/beautiful-race-condition.html. You're getting yourself into a live-lock since you're using a non-synchronized `HashMap`.

Comment: Boy that blog post sure is long! By removing the `println()`s from `run()` I was able reproduce the problem (I guess this increased my chances of overlapping as printing takes some time).This is the correct answer -> concurrent `HashMap` resizes can create a cycle in bucket lists, making it impossible to iterate to certain elements.

Comment: @JanezKuhar println is synchronized which introduces a measure of data visibility indirectly.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and interesting link! I think I can only choose one answer though. :C